# Firefox downloaded files permissions

Tags: gnome, permissions, umask

My umask is 0022, but when I download a file (using Firefox 40b11) it is created with umask 0026 (-rw-r-----). No clue where the issue is, if I'm even asking in the right forum. I'm on Mint 10 (sorry, there is no "AskMint"), Gnome desktop. I'd like downloaded files to be -rw-r--r-- so they are shareable without having to change permissions every time.

Comment: this should really be tagged "umask " but I'm not allowed to create a new tag...

Comment: What are the file-permissions of the directory you download into?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x, why?

Comment: There is a similar bug in Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 since at least Firefox 24.
This doesn't happen with Firefox 20 so the issue is probably related to Firefox. Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1227497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm getting the same issue on Mac OS X 10.6, Firefox 4.0b11. Looks like it's a Firefox bug.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I was considering that as well. I will accept your answer later, unless someone proves it wrong of course.